# Data structures- what determines inclusion in language library?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, language-features

With an assignment dealing with access control lists, it was required to construct a doubly-linked list first, as Java doesn't include that in the SUN API. I can understand if the professor wanted us to create the Doubly Linked List from scratch to understand how it works (like writing a sort program vs using the baked in methods), but why exclude it from the library?

That got me to thinking, what determines if a data structure is included in the basic language library?  For example, in Java, why is there a LinkedList class but not a DoublyLinkedList?

Comment: .NET didn't even have sets until 3.5 or so. That's just plain nuts.

Comment: Yeah it was funny seeing how some of my fellow co-workers handled unique element lists.  By funny I mean absolutely horrifying.  For instance (and I wish this were a joke)  
for(int i=0;i<myList.Count;i++) //code to look at each index   Instead of using that pesky .contains method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Java Docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> All of the operations perform as could
>   be expected for a doubly-linked list.
>   Operations that index into the list
>   will traverse the list from the
>   beginning or the end, whichever is
>   closer to the specified index.

Comment: I missed that line when I went over the linked list methods, and it threw me off a bit, as my professor said that Java does not contain a doubly linked list within the core API & we had to construct it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, of course this is opinion, that the only data structures that all programming languages have internally built into them are the following:  Array, List, Tree, Graph, and Bag.  I think List and Bag can pretty much be interchangeable in terms of vocabulary.  Keyword being think.